# Program stops when defining large dynamic 2D array in C

Tags: c

I am trying to define two dynamic 2-dimensional arrays using malloc and here is the code (I know that M = 118 and N = 186):

```
int **Cf;
Cf = (int **) malloc(M * sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)         
    Cf[i] = (int *) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
```

The array Cf allocates memory with no problem. However, my program crashes when it comes to Ct. I debugged the code and found out that `Ct[i] = (int *) malloc(N * sizeof(int))` fails when `N=164` which is kinda weird.

Comment: Perhaps better naming of your variables and symbolic constants are in order?

Comment: Why are you indexing to the wrong variable limit?  Auto-UB

Comment: And please read [this question and its answers about casting `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Rather than `N,M,i`, use something like `HEIGHT, WIDTH, h`.

Comment: Also note that you don't have any 2D arrays.

Comment: @Afshin Ahmadi  Ignore the reference "this question and its answers about casting malloc in C". There are advices of low-quakified programmers.

Comment: @xing I am a bit confused! Shouldn't I use N since I am trying to define a MxN matrix?

Comment: @AfshinAhmadi You declared at first M pointers. So the loop should use the value of M.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude actually I have a better naming of variables in my program. Just simplified it here.

Comment: @AfshinAhmadi Use castings of malloc. It makes your code more clear and readable and allows to avoid many non-obvious errors. And moreover you will be able to use such a code in C and C++ programs.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow can you give me an example?

Comment: @AfshinAhmadi Example of what?

Comment: @AfshinAhmadi To cast or not to cast, that is the [question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_be,_or_not_to_be) best for another post like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).  The best answer, IMO, is to follow your group's coding standards.

Comment: "Program stops when defining dynamic 2D array" - There is no 2D array in your code and noting which can be used as one or point to one! A pointer is not an array. (And that has nothing to do with dynamic allocation)

Comment: @xing The code crashes when the array size is like 20,000 x 20,000. But it works fine when array size is like 118x118!!!

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question, and this time put together a complete example that demonstrates it, something others could compile. You should also consider how much memory a 20kx20k array uses, perhaps you're running out. Add some error checking and narrow down the problem.

Comment: @xing I checked the malloc and it failed. The funny thing is that the first array (Cf) allocates perfectly, but when it comes to the second array (Ct) malloc fails. They both have the same size (20kx20k). I also tried calloc and encountered same issue. These variables are defined in a function. What do you think could cause this problem? I have more than enough memory on my computer!

Comment: @xing I checked the memory usage and I still have 9GB of free RAM. It is just weird. I also tried to allocate these two arrays in an empty project and it just worked fine!

Comment: @xing Do you know a more efficient way of allocating dynamic 2d arrays? I may encounter 100kx100k matrices in the future.

Comment: @xing Thank you, Xing. I will ask this question in a separate post. Stackoverflow has blocked me for 1 day because of negative points in this post!

Answer (score 1):

Key issue: Wrong range used.  Should be `<M`, not `<N`. [@xing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659534/program-stops-when-defining-dynamic-2d-array-in-c/44659704#comment76304230_44659534)

Recommend using `sizeof` against the referenced object than the type.  Easier to code, review and maintain.

Note that the casts are not required.  [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659534/program-stops-when-defining-dynamic-2d-array-in-c/44659704#comment76304306_44659534)

```
int **Cf = malloc(sizeof *CF * M);
assert(Cf);

//           M, not N
// for(i=0;i<N;i++){
for(size_t m=0; m < M; m++){ 

    printf("%zu\n", m);
    Cf[m] = malloc(sizeof *(Cf[m]) * N);
    assert(Cf[m]);
}
```

Code also used `m` instead of `i` to help make clear that the `m` index goes with `M`.

---

To use `calloc()`

```
// int **Cf = malloc(sizeof *CF * M);
int **Cf = calloc(M, sizeof *CF);

    // Cf[m] = malloc(sizeof *(Cf[m]) * N);
    Cf[m] = calloc(N, sizeof *(Cf[m]));
```

Comment: If i use calloc, I won't be able to access array elements in the form of array[i][j], right?

Comment: @AfshinAhmadi [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659534/program-stops-when-defining-dynamic-2d-array-in-c/44659704#comment76304971_44659704) is incorrect.  Code can access via `Cf[m][n]` if  `malloc()`, `calloc()` (or `realloc()` with prior allocaitons) was used like above.

Comment: The code crashes when the array size is like 20,000 x 20,000. But it works fine when array size is like 118x118!!!